# TIME_WAIT in netstat of Apache processes

Tags: apache-2.2, netstat

What are the meaning of the TIME_WAIT when using netstat of my web server process? I am sure the web server is not over loaded.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15655/apache2
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:80       123.125.66.35:19667     SYN_RECV    -
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:80       113.138.59.140:12186    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:80       66.249.67.121:59493     ESTABLISHED 23702/apache2
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:80       69.28.51.206:40652      TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:80       221.126.149.99:51877    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:80       221.126.149.99:51872    TIME_WAIT   -
tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:80       123.125.66.19:13084     TIME_WAIT   -
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article I often point people to when they ask this. http://antmeetspenguin.blogspot.com/2008/10/timewait-in-netstat.html

In short - it can be complicated.  There is a lot of good information in that article though, read up.